# Run code once on page load, then every time a button is clicked

Tags: jquery

I need to have a function run once when the page is loaded, and then again whenever a button is pressed.  If I take out the code to run it on page load, it works whenever the button is pressed, otherwise it only runs once on page load and never when the button is pressed.

```
$(function()
{
    // code to be run
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#button").click(function()
    {
        // code to be run
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, I moved the location of one of the function calls and it now works perfectly.  However, I'd still like to know why it would work with the function call for click in one place but not the other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function run(){
    //code to run
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#button").click(function()
    {
        run()
    });
    run()
});
```

Comment: That didn't work.  An update didn't happen when I clicked on the button.  :(

Comment: @atrox, Please post the code you use to update. are you sure you have a element with a ID "button"? add a `alert(1)` inside the `run()` function, see if that works.

Comment: That works, but not when I have my $.post() code in it instead.

Answer (score 2):

Define a function:

```
$(function() {
    var your_code = function() {
        // code to be run
    };
    $("#button").click(your_code);
    your_code();
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VdU3X/).

Comment: This still only updated when I first opened the page, not when I clicked the button.

Comment: Hmmmm, I don't get why it's not working with $.post().  I used alerts to test it and it worked just fine.  :(

Comment: You'll have to show us your current code for any further debugging.  There must be another issue besides this.