# Run jQuery Function on Page Load AND Every Time Certain Buttons Are Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `ul` with multiple list items and am using jQuery to:

1. Count the number of list items
2. Output that value to a different div
3. Change the color of the output text if that value is greater than 13

In a different div, I have multiple buttons with the class `.add` or `.delete`. Not surprisingly, clicking these buttons adds or deletes list items.

The jQuery function works perfectly when the page is loaded, but what I'd like to also do is have this count update every time one of the above buttons is clicked.

Here's my existing code:

```
    var totalItems = $('ul#myList li').length;
    $('#outputText').text(totalItems);
    if (totalItems > 13) {
        $('#outputText').css('color','#F0402B');
    };
```

What do I need to add to make this work? I did look at the answers for this similar question ([Run code once on page load, then every time a button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683919/run-code-once-on-page-load-then-every-time-a-button-is-clicked)) but they didn't seem to help. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That code should work for you. You just need to package your code to the different events. What part is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apologies if I'm missing something, but basically: Just wrap the code up in a function, call that function on page load, and also call the function after processing the clicks on the buttons.

E.g.:

```
// The function
function updateTotalItems() {
    var totalItems = $('ul#myList li').length;
    $('#outputText').text(totalItems);
    if (totalItems > 13) {
        $('#outputText').css('color','#F0402B');
    };
}

// Call on page load
$(updateTotalItems);

// Presumably you're setting up click handlers
$(".add, .delete").click(function() {
    // Process the add or delete action

    // Update the total
    updateTotalItems();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Keep this function outside of document ready to avoid anonymous function.     
function updateDiv(){
var totalItems = $('ul#myList li').length;
    $('#outputText').text(totalItems);
    if (totalItems > 13) 
        {
        $('#outputText').css('color','#F0402B');
        }
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
   // do stuff when DOM is ready
   updateDiv();
   $('.delete').click(updateDiv());
   $('.add').click(updateDiv());
 });
```